# How do I specify that a Higher Order Component should accept a property in addition to the remaining properties of the base component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I am trying to learn React / Redux usage with higher order components in a Typescript environment. I have two higher order components:

1. *withId*: Generates uniqueId property for base component
2. *withErrorListener*: Renders errors on the redux store, originating from a base component request. The base component should have the uniqueId property created from the *withId* higher order component.

NewComponent = withErrorListener(withId(BaseComponent))

```js
const PostsListWithId = withId(PostsListBase);
export const PostsListConnected = connector(withErrorListener(PostsListWithId));
```

I am consuming the HoC's as follows:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { RootState } from "typesafe-actions";

import { Post as PostComponent } from "../components/Post";

import { allPostsAction, createPostsRequest } from "../features/posts/actions";
import { HocComponentProps } from "../higher-order-components/types";
import { Post } from "../features/posts/types";
import { withErrorListener } from "../higher-order-components/withErrorListener";
import { withId } from "../higher-order-components/componentId/withId";

type StateProps = {
  isLoading: boolean;
  posts: Post[];
};

/**
 * Redux dispatch and state mappings
 */
const dispatchProps = {
  fetchPosts: allPostsAction.request
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState): StateProps => ({
  isLoading: state.posts.isLoadingPosts,
  posts: state.posts.posts
});

const connector = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  dispatchProps
);

type ReduxProps = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;

/**
 * Component property type definitions
 */
type Props = ReduxProps & HocComponentProps;

/**
 * CourseList component
 */
const PostsListBase = ({
  posts = [],
  uniqueId,
  fetchPosts,
  isLoading
}: Props): JSX.Element => {
  console.log(`PostListBase id :: ${uniqueId}`);

  // dispatch fetch posts action on mount
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(
      `PostListBase dispatching PostsRequest action with id ${uniqueId}`
    );
    fetchPosts(createPostsRequest(uniqueId));
  }, [fetchPosts, uniqueId]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <>
        <p>Loading...</p>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: 20, padding: 30 }}>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <h2>List of post id's</h2>
      {
        <ul>
          {posts.map(element => (
            <li key={element.id}>
              <PostComponent post={element} />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      }
    </div>
  );
};

const PostsListWithId = withId(PostsListBase);
export const PostsListConnected = connector(withErrorListener(PostsListWithId));

/**
 * Argument of type 'typeof IdHoC' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<ExpectedProps>'.
  Type 'typeof IdHoC' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<ExpectedProps, any>'.
    Types of parameters 'hocprops' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type 'ExpectedProps' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<Props, "posts" | "fetchPosts" | "isLoading">': posts, fetchPosts, isLoadingts(2345)
 */
```

However, I am receiving the following typescript compilation error:

```sh
Argument of type 'typeof IdHoC' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<ExpectedProps>'.
  Type 'typeof IdHoC' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<ExpectedProps, any>'.
    Types of parameters 'hocprops' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type 'ExpectedProps' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<Props, "posts" | "fetchPosts" | "isLoading">': posts, fetchPosts, isLoadingts(2345)
```

How do I correctly specify that the *withErrorListener* higher order component should accept a type that includes a *uniqueId* property in addition to the remaining properties in the base component, in this case: {posts, fetchPosts and isLoading}?

I am currently trying to do this in the code as follows:

```js
type ExpectedProps = { uniqueId: string };
export const withErrorListener = <BaseProps extends ExpectedProps>(
  BaseComponent: React.ComponentType<BaseProps>
) => {....}
```

I have created a codesandbox project, including the source for higher order components, here:

[image: Edit React Redux Typescript Nested Connected HoC Example - Forked]

Think that I have managed to solve the issue. One of the issues was raised in comments below, regarding *withId* returning a wrapped component excluding injected id property. Have removed this constraint and accepting that comment as the solution. The other issue was that the consuming component requires properties connected to the redux store for receiving fetched state from an Api. Updated the consumer of the Higher Component to be:

```
// ensure consuming component is connected to redux store to fulfill it's other property requirements
const PostsListConnectedWithId = connector(withId(PostsListBase));
export const PostsListWithErrorListener = withErrorListener(PostsListConnectedWithId);
```

typescript

as opposed to:

```js
const PostsListWithId = withId(PostsListBase);
export const PostsListWithErrorListener = connector(withErrorListener(PostsListWithId));
```

Including link to forked sandbox in case anyone else experiences similar issues:
[image: Edit React Redux Typescript Nested Connected HoC Example - AttemptingToSolve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've look into you CodeSandbox sample, I don't really understand what is your need.

So in you code, `withId` HoC takes a base comp, in your case `PostsListBase`, and inject `uniqueId` prop to it, then return a wrapped comp that **no longer needs** `uniqueId` as prop input, since it already got it from `withId`.

Then you put `WrappedPostsListBase` that no longer want a `uniqueId` through `withErrorListener(WrappedPostsListBase)`.

Here's the confusing part, you specify that `withErrorListener` only accepts a base comp input that **require** a `uniqueId` prop. See the conflict?

Comment: Hi thanks for responding @hackape. I am trying to have two HoC's: withId injects uniqueId property and withErrorListener accepts a component created from withId. The component passed to withErrorListener should have uniqueId property.....

Comment: Thanks @hackape, have forked codesandbox and removed the constraint in withId concerning returning wrapped comp without uniqueId property...Issue still occurs...

Comment: Also removed constraint in codesandbox for withId that returns wrapped comp that no longer needs uniqueId.....

Comment: Edited question introduction to state that the base component should have the uniqueId property created from the withId higher order component and included a usage example...